# Online Resources for SignalR Core

Tags: signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Can someone please point me to a good online resource where I can read up on signalr Core that just got released with .net core 2.0? The only example I've seen is sending message from the Hub class to connected browsers like this:

```
namespace MyTestApp
{
    public class Notify : Hub
    {
        public Task Send(string message)
        {
            return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message);
        }
    }
}
```

But what about other examples, like someone replied to your post for example...

Comment: shameless plug: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/09/18/the-signalr-for-asp-net-core-javascript-client-part-1-web-applications/

Comment: another one: https://radu-matei.com/blog/signalr-core/

Answer (score 1):

Use official samples on:

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples

The code explains the things very vell. Together with
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/ (short introduction about changes) and together with the documentation for older version (https://www.asp.net/signalr) you can start (documentation is old but the most of concepts are equals).